# Laravel redirect detection

Tags: php, laravel

How can I actually detect that the user was redirected to the page? I want to flush the cache each time that user was redirected after POST request. I've tried it doing like

```php
if(http_response_code() == 304)
{
   //
}
```

But, while using

```php
dd(http_response_code());
```

It gives me `200` anyway, no matter was there a redirect or not. Any choices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing the redirection only internally through your application, you could do this by saving an attribute through Laravel sessions.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#storing-data

Where you actually launch your redirect:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

Session::put('redirectToUsersPage', '1');
return redirect()->route('route')->with($data);
```

Within your controller of the page you redirected to:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;    

if ( Session::get('redirectToUsersPage') ) {
// This was a redirected request, lets do our logic.
Session::forget('redirectToUsersPage');
}
```

Comment: No problem, i'll update so it uses the public Session facade.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I've managed to get it working via $request, but I like the Session way more